# Clicking on a link should pop my application

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter

Right now, I'm using android:ssp to filter the path of url and this is available from API 19.

How do I filter the url path for API 10 onwards?

```
scheme://host/path/token
```

is my url pattern.

**EDIT:**

I have tried android:path="/path/*" but it isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<intent-filter>
<data android:scheme="scheme" android:host="host" /></intent-filter>
```

The way I'm trying to implement may cause [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25155983/android-intent-filter-data-pathprefix-catches-when-not-exists-in-the-url) error

Finally decided not use path, filtering using host and handling it with the data in my activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an intent filter on the same activity that uses the [data element](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#DataTest) to filter on the Uri. You can add this filter after your ssp filter on the same activity.

I think the correct intent filter would look something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <data android:scheme="scheme" android:host="host" android:path="path/*" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Edit:**

From the linked documentation:

```
Note: A path specification can contain a wildcard asterisk (*) to require only a partial match of the path name.
```

So this allows you to use an asterisk in your path for the token.

Comment: I tried that already, the point is, I have to give a partial path to my url, the token in my url always change 'scheme://host/path/token '

Comment: yes, you are absolutely right, but, `android:path="/path/*" ` is not working, I should have mentioned in the question itself, my bad. I will correct it